# Rails- Mongoid query to filter objects based on length of a field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, mongodb-query, mongoid

I want to filter a collection based on the length of a field.
Example : For collection Band, i would want the objects where the length of the name of band is equal to 10.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways I can think to do this. In these examples, let's pretend I have the following model:

```
class Band
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :name, type: String
end
```

### Aggregation

If you're using MongoDB server version 3.6 or newer, you can use the [`$expr`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/) operator to include aggregation operations in your query. In this example, I'm using the [`$strLenCP`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/strLenCP/) operator to find any documents where the `name` field has 5 Unicode code points:

```
Band.where("$expr": { "$eq": [ { "$strLenCP": "$name" }, 5 ] })
```

### Regular Expressions

You could also use a Ruby regular expression that matches any five-character string:

```
Band.where(name: /\A.{5}\z/)
```

I suspect aggregation will be more performant, but it can't hurt to know a few ways of doing something.